# Partial window in popup window

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my code to open a partial view in popup window, which does not happen. Please let me know where is it that I'm going wrong.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu place-right" data-role="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#" id="register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="login">Login</a></li>
</ul>

<script>       
$(function () {      
        $.Dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            shadow: true,
            overlay: false,
            draggable: true,
            icon: '<span class="icon-bus"></span>',
            title: 'Register',
            width: 500,
            padding: 10,
            content: 'Register with StudiDesk',
            open: function (event, ui) {                    
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("Register")");
                $.Dialog.title("Sign UP");
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).Dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    $("#register").click(function () {
        $.Dialog('open');
    });
});
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return PartialView("_register");
}
```

Comment: Any error browser console?

Comment: I'd say you should replace both $.Dialog(...) occurences by $(#SomeElementId).Dialog(...) and define placeholder <div id="SomeElementId" style="display:none"></div>